# What methods are there for extracting featues like local extrema and flat parts from a dataset?

Tags: c, algorithm, dataset, feature-extraction, data-extraction

I need to extract specific predefined features from a list of datasets. 
Here are two exaple plots of the datasets I am using:

[image]

[image]

My goal is to create an algorithm using C to extract the initial maximum, the time the maximum drops off, the width of the initial peak, the length of the flat part of the curve, etc..

I **don't** need code to get these exact features from this exact dataset. I am asking for current techniques and methods that are being used in this type of problem. Different algorithms and approches that have been proven to work.

Any leads in the right direction would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: if you are looking for algorithms rather than code, then you might be better off posting in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are right. I will leave it here for a while and see if I get some more feedback. Then I will post it in Computer Science.